# How to read xml file from url using python

Tags: python

I've extracted xml links from the following website.
https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/shp/scripcode/532892/flag/7/
I am using selenium and beautifulsoup for this process. But I am finding it difficult to read the xml data from the links I've extracted. When I used xml.etree.ElementTree to read it threw the following error urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found because urlopen method is not able to read the response from the link.

Below is my code that I've written for your reference.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTML, HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request as request
from selenium import webdriver
import xmltodict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/shp/scripcode/532892/flag/7/'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
htmlSource = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, 'html5lib')
div_tbl = soup.find_all("div", style="margin-top: 10px;")
h = div_tbl[0].find_all('a',target='_blank')
xml_links=[]
for i in h:
    if '.xml' in i['href']:
        xml_links.append('http://www.bseindia.com'+i['href'])

document = request.urlopen(xml_links[0]).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(document)
```

Sorry for my bad english. Any help as to how to proceed is greatly appreciated.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to check if you create correct url to xml.

Comment: server may use special methods to check if you use real web browser to download it - ie. it can check HTTP headers or cookies - so it may be simpler to use module `requests`, instead of `urllib`

Answer (score 0):

Server may use special methods to check if you use real web browser to download it - ie. it can check HTTP headers or cookies.

If I use `requests` with header `User-Agent` (even with short `Mozilla/5.0` instead of header from real web browser) then it gets `XML`. If I skip `headers` then it gets error `404`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/shp/scripcode/532892/flag/7/'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')

all_divs = soup.find_all("div", style="margin-top: 10px;")
all_links = all_divs[0].find_all('a', target='_blank')
xml_links = []
for link in all_links:
    if link['href'].endswith('.xml'):
        url = 'https://www.bseindia.com' + link['href']
        #print(url)
        xml_links.append(url)

# ---

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}

response = requests.get(xml_links[0], headers=headers)
print('status:', response.status_code)

document = response.content
print('document:', document[:100])

tree = ET.fromstring(document)
print('tree:', tree)
```

Result:

```
status: 200
document: b'\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\r\n<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:in-bse-shp="http://www.bseindia.com/xbr'
tree: <Element '{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl' at 0x7f505ea1c630>
```